# All the squares in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, terminology

I just want to know what this statement means:

> all the squares in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$.

Comment: probably the element which can be writen as $a^2$ for some $a\in Z_n$*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group $\mathbb{Z}_n^{\ast}$  denotes the multiplicative group of invertible residue classes  modulo $n$, that is those generated by elements relatively prime to $n$.

The squares in this group are just the elements that you get considering $a^2$ for $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n^{\ast}$.

For context, note that one says that an element $x$ is a [quadratic residue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) modulo $n$ if it is of the form $a^2$ modulo $n$. However, there is in general  no restriction that the class is also relatively prime to $n$. So, what you consider is more specific than being a quadratic residue modulo $n$.

Comment: So I would have to find such that $ax \equiv 1 \mod n$ and then square the elements found in the previous steo

Comment: Yes more or less. It is slightly easier to check for $0 \le a \le n -1$ if $\gcd (a,n)=1$, the second criterion I gave, and then take $a^2$.

Answer (score 2):

First it should be denoted $\mathbb Z_n^\times$. The units (elements which have a multiplicative inverse) in the ring $\mathbb Z_n$ are a (multiplicative) group. It consists of the congruence classes modulo $n$ of integers which are coprime with $n$. The squares are – well… the squares of these elements.

Here is an example: $\mathbb Z_{12}^\times=\{1,5,7,11\}$ (I don't use a special notation to make the difference between an integer and its class modulo $12$). It is a multiplicative group of order $4$: indeed 
$$5\cdot 7=11,\quad 5\cdot 11=7, \quad 7\cdot 11=5,\quad 1^2=5^2=7^2=11^2=1.$$